# janusgraph with OneTimeBulkLoader in hadoop-gremlin raise "Graph does not support adding vertices"

Tags: hadoop, graph, gremlin, vertices, janusgraph

**my goal:** 
    uses SparkGraphComputer to bulkLoader local data to janusgraph and then build mixed index on hbase and ES

**my problem:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Graph does not support adding vertices
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph$Exceptions.vertexAdditionsNotSupported(Graph.java:1133)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph.addVertex(HadoopGraph.java:187)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.AddVertexStartStep.processNextStart(AddVertexStartStep.java:91)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:128)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:38)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:200)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.bulkloading.OneTimeBulkLoader.getOrCreateVertex(OneTimeBulkLoader.java:49)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.bulkloading.BulkLoaderVertexProgram.executeInternal(BulkLoaderVertexProgram.java:210)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.computer.bulkloading.BulkLoaderVertexProgram.execute(BulkLoaderVertexProgram.java:197)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.SparkExecutor.lambda$null$4(SparkExecutor.java:118)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.util.iterator.IteratorUtils$3.next(IteratorUtils.java:247)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    ... 3 more
```

**dependences:**

janusgraph-all-0.3.1
janusgraph-es-0.3.1
hadoop-gremlin-3.3.3

**The followings is configuration:**

1. janusgraph-hbase-es.properties

   ```
   storage.backend=hbase
   gremlin.graph=XXX.XXX.XXX.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph
   storage.hostname=<ip>
   storage.hbase.table=hadoop-test-3
   storage.batch-loading=true
   schema.default = none
   cache.db-cache = true
   cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
   cache.db-cache-time = 180000
   cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
   index.search.backend=elasticsearch
   index.search.hostname=<ip>
   index.search.index-name=hadoop_test_3
   ```
2. hadoop-graphson.properties

   ```
   gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph
   gremlin.hadoop.graphReader=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONInputFormat
   gremlin.hadoop.graphWriter=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONOutputFormat
   gremlin.hadoop.inputLocation=data/tinkerpop-modern.json
   gremlin.hadoop.outputLocation=output
   gremlin.hadoop.jarsInDistributedCache=true

   giraph.minWorkers=2
   giraph.maxWorkers=2
   giraph.useOutOfCoreGraph=true
   giraph.useOutOfCoreMessages=true
   mapred.map.child.java.opts=-Xmx1024m
   mapred.reduce.child.java.opts=-Xmx1024m
   giraph.numInputThreads=4
   giraph.numComputeThreads=4
   giraph.maxMessagesInMemory=100000

   spark.master=local[*]
   spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
   ```
3. schema.groovy

   ```
   def defineGratefulDeadSchema(janusGraph) {
       JanusGraphManagement m = janusGraph.openManagement()
       VertexLabel person = m.makeVertexLabel("person").make()
       //使用IncrementBulkLoader导入时，去掉下面注释         
       //blid=m.makePropertyKey("bulkLoader.vertex.id")
         .dataType(Long.class).make()
       PropertyKey birth = 
         m.makePropertyKey("birth").dataType(Date.class).make()
       PropertyKey age = 
         m.makePropertyKey("age").dataType(Integer.class).make()
       PropertyKey name = 
         m.makePropertyKey("name").dataType(String.class).make()
       //index 
       //JanusGraphIndex index = m
         .buildIndex("nameCompositeIndex", 
         Vertex.class).addKey(name).unique().buildCompositeIndex()
       JanusGraphIndex index = m.buildIndex("mixedIndex", 
         Vertex.class).addKey(name).buildMixedIndex("search")
         //不支持唯一性检查，search为index.search.backend中的search
       //使用IncrementBulkLoader导入时，去掉下面注释
       //bidIndex = m.buildIndex("byBulkLoaderVertexId",     
         Vertex.class).addKey(blid).indexOnly(person)
         .buildCompositeIndex()
       m.commit()
   }
   ```
4. relevant code

   ```
   JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.open
     ("config/janusgraph-hbase-es.properties");
   JanusgraphSchema janusgraphSchema = new JanusgraphSchema();
   janusgraphSchema.defineGratefulDeadSchema(janusGraph);
   janusGraph.close();

   Graph graph = GraphFactory.open("config/hadoop-
     graphson.properties");
   BulkLoaderVertexProgram blvp = BulkLoaderVertexProgram.
     build().bulkLoader(OneTimeBulkLoader.class).
     writeGraph("config/janusgraph-hbase-es.properties").
     create(graph);
   graph.compute(SparkGraphComputer.class).program(blvp).
     submit().get();
   graph.close();

   JanusGraph janusGraph1 = JanusGraphFactory.open
     ("config/janusgraph-hbase-es.properties");
   List<Map<String, Object>> list = janusGraph1.traversal().V().
     valueMap().toList();
   System.out.println("size: " + list.size());
   janusGraph1.close();
   ```

**result：**

```
data success to import hbase, but fail to build index in ES
```

Answer (score 0):

The above error does not appear, after I reset gremlin.graph with default value gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.